# ESLint plugin (using ESLint API) async preprocess?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying my hand at upgrading a very old ESLint plugin to something more modern.
One of the problems is that in ESLint 8+, the API for getting config from a file is now async, so what was previously:

```js
preprocess(text, filename) {
    const config = new CLIEngine({ useEslintrc: true }).getConfigForFile(path.resolve(filename));
   /* ... */
   return [preprocessed]
}
```

Is now:

```js
async preprocess(text, filename) {
    const eslint = new ESLint();
    var config = await eslint.calculateConfigForFile(filename);
    /* ... */
    return [preprocessed]
}
```

The problem is that ESLint doesn't seem to expect the preprocess function to be async, so it ends up treating it as an array (which is its original return value) when it is in fact a Promise.

This could be easily solved by adding an `await` before whatever code calls for the preprocessor, but I'm not sure that's something I can configure (or can I? Please let me know if I can).

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Can the preprocessor be called with `await` or can the config be retrieved synchronously?

Thanks in advance!

** UPDATE **
On their github, the eslint maintainers said what I'm looking to do isn't possible. I've instead elected to not use the config at all and find a different solution for my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5136 seems relevant

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not entirely sure how it's relevant (I could be misreading it?). Either way, they closed it due to "lack of consensus" :-/

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14745 - seems to be around the same topic.

Comment: The issue asked to make the config available to the `preprocess` function as a third parameter. (Loading/calculating the config in the function itself, like you were doing, doesn't make sense). It was closed as there appeared to be no good use case for it. I'm certain that if you can make a convincing case, they'd be happy to add it, but it does indeed appear to be impossible currently.

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks. I'll post my use-case there :-)